# Cannot connect to Google cloud SQL from App Engine Standard Environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-iam

I have recently switch my code to another project.
I use the Public IP method addressed in [official document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine-standard) but to no avail.

In the log explorer, I have seen a lot of warning entries state that:

> CloudSQL warning: your action is needed to update your application and avoid potential disruptions. Please see https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard for  additional details:

> Post `https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/instances/asia-east1~<CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE>:generateEphemeralCert?alt=json&prettyPrint=false`: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = IAM permission denied for service account gae-deploy@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com.

Things I have confirmed and checked:

- New cloud SQL and app engine are on the same project
- `Cloud SQL Admin API` is enabled
- App engine region is `asia-east1` (same as the cloud SQL region)
- App engine service account and GAE cloud deploy accounts have `Cloud SQL Admin` role
- Default service account `[PROJECT_ID]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` has the following roles:

  - `Cloud SQL Admin`, `Editor`, `Service Account Token Creator`, `Storage Object Admin`
- Created service account `gae-deploy@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com` has the following roles:

  - `App Engine Service Admin`, `Cloud Build Service Account`, `Cloud SQL Admin`, `Cloud SQL Client`, `Serverless VPC Access User`, `Service Account User`

According to the documents, `Cloud SQL Client` role is enough. But the logs keep telling me that the service account cannot access the cloud sql admin API.

What am I doing wrong? Or which additional IAM roles should I grant to the service accounts?

Comment: When you say you've switched to another project, does that mean your app is in one project and the Cloud SQL instance is in another project? If so, you'll need to ensure the service account associated with the app is a member of the other project.

Comment: new app engine and new cloud sql are on the same project

Comment: I would expect that if the Admin API were enabled, the App Engine service account had Cloud SQL Client, and the instance connection name was correct, it would work. Try verifying your instance connection name which should be ` /cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME`.

Comment: yes, `/cloutsql/instance_onnection_name` is what I use for connection.
I found a github thread with a similar problem. Not sure whether it is the same case. 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/issues/37#issuecomment-297265064

Comment: Did you try the work-around in the comment? I would be very surprised if that fixed the issue.

Comment: @enocom it works! I will answer my own question later when my delayed tasks are done

Comment: Glad to hear, but sorry to hear that this bug bit you. Seems that old service accounts might have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the similar steps mentioned on [this github thread comment](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/issues/37#issuecomment-297265064).
Steps I have done:

- remove ALL roles for both default app engine service account `[PROJECT_ID]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` and `gae-deploy@<PROJECT_ID>.iam.gserviceaccount.com`
- Add the same roles back
- Rebuild app engine

Now everything is usual