# App Engine fails to connect to mysql cloud sql (failed to refresh the ephemeral certificate)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Been using App Engine Standard for years, connecting to mysql via socket without issue.

Today, started seeing this error in the logs:

> failed to refresh the ephemeral certificate for xxxxx:us-east1:xxxxx: Post "https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/xxxxx/instances/us-east1~xxxxx-db:generateEphemeralCert?alt=json&prettyPrint=false": rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = IAM permission denied for service account xxxxxx@appspot.gserviceaccount.com.

Nothing has changed with permissions and I have verified the service account has "Editor" and "Cloud SQL Client" roles.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot connect to Google cloud SQL from App Engine Standard Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71873881/cannot-connect-to-google-cloud-sql-from-app-engine-standard-environment)

Answer (score 2):

This issue was resolved for me by enabling Cloud SQL Admin API.

[image]